# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Xamarin Android

Tags: xamarin, bitmap, xamarin.android, out-of-memory, segmentation-fault

Getting **`java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`** While trying to GetPixels  of `mutable` copy of the Bitmap.

Here is the code:

```
public async Task<Bitmap> LoadScaledDownBitmapForDisplayAsync(string path, BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight)
{
    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.InSampleSize = CalculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);
    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set       
    options.InJustDecodeBounds = true;        
    Bitmap mutableBitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeFile(path, options);
    Bitmap bitmap = mutableBitmap.Copy(Bitmap.Config.Argb8888, true);        
    allpixels = new int[bitmap.Height * bitmap.Width];
    bitmap.GetPixels(allpixels, 0, bitmap.Width, 0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);
    Bitmap bitmapToDisplay = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < allpixels.Length; i++)
     {
     if (allpixels[i] == Color.Black)
     {
      allpixels[i] = Color.Gray;
      int alpha = 0x00;
      allpixels[i] = Color.Red;

      bitmap.SetPixels(allpixels, 0, bitmap.Width, 0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);
             }
            }

    return bitmap;
}
```

Error:

```
05-25 17:24:41.945 D/dalvikvm(12002): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 701K, 2% free 259110K/261936K, paused 53ms, total 54ms
05-25 17:24:42.850 I/dalvikvm-heap(12002): Clamp target GC heap from 256.376MB to 256.000MB
05-25 17:24:42.850 D/dalvikvm(12002): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 276K, 1% free 259383K/261936K, paused 59ms, total 59ms
05-25 17:24:42.890 I/dalvikvm-heap(12002): Clamp target GC heap from 256.643MB to 256.000MB
05-25 17:24:42.890 D/dalvikvm(12002): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 1% free 259655K/261936K, paused 37ms, total 37ms
05-25 17:24:42.890 I/dalvikvm-heap(12002): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 281824-byte allocation
05-25 17:24:42.930 I/dalvikvm-heap(12002): Clamp target GC heap from 258.635MB to 256.000MB
05-25 17:24:42.930 D/dalvikvm(12002): GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 10K, 1% free 259645K/261936K, paused 42ms, total 42ms
05-25 17:24:42.930 E/dalvikvm-heap(12002): Out of memory on a 281824-byte allocation.
05-25 17:24:42.930 I/dalvikvm(12002): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
05-25 17:24:42.930 I/dalvikvm(12002):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x41caa578 self=0x41c88a60
05-25 17:24:42.930 I/dalvikvm(12002):   | sysTid=12002 nice=-16 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1074249724
05-25 17:24:42.930 I/dalvikvm(12002):   | state=R schedstat=( 763705373545 16690026208 56421 ) utm=75810 stm=560 core=3
05-25 17:24:42.930 I/dalvikvm(12002):   at mono.android.view.View_OnClickListenerImplementor.n_onClick(Native Method)
05-25 17:24:42.930 I/dalvikvm(12002):   at mono.android.view.View_OnClickListenerImplementor.onClick(View_OnClickListenerImplementor.java:29)
05-25 17:24:42.930 I/dalvikvm(12002):   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4475)
05-25 17:24:42.930 I/dalvikvm(12002):   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18786)
05-25 17:24:42.930 I/dalvikvm(12002):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
05-25 17:24:42.930 I/dalvikvm(12002):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-25 17:24:42.930 I/dalvikvm(12002):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
05-25 17:24:42.930 I/dalvikvm(12002):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
05-25 17:24:42.930 I/dalvikvm(12002):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-25 17:24:42.930 I/dalvikvm(12002):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
05-25 17:24:42.930 I/dalvikvm(12002):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
05-25 17:24:42.930 I/dalvikvm(12002):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
05-25 17:24:42.935 I/dalvikvm(12002):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-25 17:24:42.935 I/dalvikvm(12002): 
05-25 17:24:42.935 W/dalvikvm(12002): JNI WARNING: JNI method called with exception pending
05-25 17:24:42.935 W/dalvikvm(12002):              in Lmono/android/view/View_OnClickListenerImplementor;.n_onClick:(Landroid/view/View;)V (SetIntArrayRegion)
05-25 17:24:42.935 W/dalvikvm(12002): Pending exception is:
05-25 17:24:42.935 I/dalvikvm(12002): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError:
05-25 17:24:42.935 I/dalvikvm(12002):   at mono.android.view.View_OnClickListenerImplementor.n_onClick(Native Method)
05-25 17:24:42.935 I/dalvikvm(12002):   at mono.android.view.View_OnClickListenerImplementor.onClick(View_OnClickListenerImplementor.java:29)
05-25 17:24:42.935 I/dalvikvm(12002):   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4475)
05-25 17:24:42.935 I/dalvikvm(12002):   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18786)
05-25 17:24:42.935 I/dalvikvm(12002):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
05-25 17:24:42.935 I/dalvikvm(12002):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-25 17:24:42.935 I/dalvikvm(12002):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
05-25 17:24:42.935 I/dalvikvm(12002):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
05-25 17:24:42.935 I/dalvikvm(12002):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-25 17:24:42.935 I/dalvikvm(12002):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
05-25 17:24:42.935 I/dalvikvm(12002):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
05-25 17:24:42.935 I/dalvikvm(12002):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
05-25 17:24:42.935 I/dalvikvm(12002):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-25 17:24:42.935 I/dalvikvm(12002): "main" prio=5 tid=1 NATIVE
05-25 17:24:42.935 I/dalvikvm(12002):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x41caa578 self=0x41c88a60
05-25 17:24:42.935 I/dalvikvm(12002):   | sysTid=12002 nice=-16 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1074249724
05-25 17:24:42.935 I/dalvikvm(12002):   | state=R schedstat=( 763706606629 16692302499 56458 ) utm=75810 stm=560 core=3
05-25 17:24:42.935 I/dalvikvm(12002):   #00  pc 000012fe  /system/lib/libcorkscrew.so (unwind_backtrace_thread+29)
05-25 17:24:42.935 I/dalvikvm(12002):   #01  pc 00060b82  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmDumpNativeStack(DebugOutputTarget const*, int)+33)
05-25 17:24:42.935 I/dalvikvm(12002):   #02  pc 00054c20  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmDumpThreadEx(DebugOutputTarget const*, Thread*, bool)+395)
05-25 17:24:42.935 I/dalvikvm(12002):   #03  pc 00054c8e  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmDumpThread(Thread*, bool)+25)
05-25 17:24:42.935 I/dalvikvm(12002):   #04  pc 00038f00  /system/lib/libdvm.so
05-25 17:24:42.935 I/dalvikvm(12002):   #05  pc 0003af50  /system/lib/libdvm.so
05-25 17:24:42.935 I/dalvikvm(12002):   at mono.android.view.View_OnClickListenerImplementor.n_onClick(Native Method)
05-25 17:24:42.935 I/dalvikvm(12002):   at mono.android.view.View_OnClickListenerImplementor.onClick(View_OnClickListenerImplementor.java:29)
05-25 17:24:42.935 I/dalvikvm(12002):   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4475)
05-25 17:24:42.935 I/dalvikvm(12002):   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18786)
05-25 17:24:42.935 I/dalvikvm(12002):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
05-25 17:24:42.935 I/dalvikvm(12002):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-25 17:24:42.935 I/dalvikvm(12002):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
05-25 17:24:42.935 I/dalvikvm(12002):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
05-25 17:24:42.935 I/dalvikvm(12002):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-25 17:24:42.935 I/dalvikvm(12002):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
05-25 17:24:42.935 I/dalvikvm(12002):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
05-25 17:24:42.935 I/dalvikvm(12002):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
In mgmain JNI_OnLoad
05-25 17:24:42.940 I/dalvikvm(12002):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-25 17:24:42.940 I/dalvikvm(12002): 
05-25 17:24:42.940 E/dalvikvm(12002): VM aborting
05-25 17:24:42.945 E/mono-rt (12002): Stacktrace:
05-25 17:24:42.945 E/mono-rt (12002):
```

And Finally Getting this Message:

```
Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
05-25 17:24:42.985 E/mono-rt (12002): a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
05-25 17:24:42.985 E/mono-rt (12002): used by your application.
```

Any Idea or help would be really helpful.

Comment: How large is your image? You can't decode huge images without getting a OutOfMemoryException. Or your memory is full already.

Comment: @Sven-MichaelStübe i can able to display the image in ImageView without error ,But while trying to get the mutable copy of the Bitmap,I am facing this Error.

Comment: Does CalculateInSampleSize inflate the full bitmap to get measurements? Perhaps inside there you need to set injustdecodebounds = true. I cant see that code but would venture to guess you might be inflating the bitmap to get sizing then inflating a new one as mutable?

Comment: Have you had a look at the memory heap? You can do so by using Android Studio. I have personally been facing the same problem previously, and the memory dump indicated, that all instances of `bItmaps` ever created were kept in the memory. This is because, that they are not automatically garbage collected. If that's the case, then you could consider disposing the bitmaps yourself.

Comment: @Demitrian the same code is working perfectly in Android Studio without Errors.

Comment: @ClintLandry I have changed injustdecodebounds = true. but seems the same issue

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend using `using` statements all around your bitmap code. That should help dispose of the proper peer wrapper. If you don't use `using` statements, then ensure you are calling `.Dipose()` or setting the peer wrapper to `null` to sever the connection.

Secondly, I would also recommend a manual `GC` invoke via `GC.Collect()` or `JavaSystem.GC()` to help reduce the working set at the end of your operation.

i.e.:

```
using (var bitmap = HowIGetThisBitMap())
{
    //How I use this bitmap while in scope
}

GC.Collect(); //I then ensure I manually invoke the GC
```

Yes this is somewhat against traditional .NET items, but we are on a mobile device where we have memory sensitive operations. This is especially the case for lower-end devices that don't have a large RAM cache. This is specifically one spot of code that we would want to call `GC.Collect()`.